# Apache http + mod-rewrite to Tomcat to lose apps subfolder from the url

Tags: regex, http, tomcat, mod-rewrite, proxypass

I am using a Tomcat server for my applications that is accessible from Apache HTTP through ajp.

The urls that are generated by the various apps on the Tomcat server, need to be accessed through //control/

This looks like following overview:

- //www.example.com/app1/control/index
- //www.example.com/app2/control/index
- //www.example.com/app3/control/index
- //www.example.com/app3/control/otherurl
- .
- //www.example.com/appN/control/index.jsp

While this is acceptable for me, it is not very user friendly and I would like to improve that through offering shorter urls. As I see it the /control or control/ is superfluous, because it would be much more user friendly to present:

- //www.example.com/app1/index
- //www.example.com/app2/index
- //www.example.com/app2/otherurl
- .
- .
- //www.example.com/appN/index

Now, i could do the proxypass / proxyreversepass per app, but that is a cumbersome process. So I would like to have it solved by applying a regex. But I am a bit stumped at how to do the url rewrite and proxypass / proxyreversepass to get it working.

Could you help me out, to get to the right solution?

Best regards,

Pierre Smits

Comment: Apache httpd version?

Comment: That is Apache httpd 2.2.22

Comment: Are all the applications going to be accessed through the same backend AJP URL?

Comment: @christopher-schultz Yes, they are.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`ProxyPassMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch). Something like this:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/app([0-9]+)/(.*)$ ajp://tomcathost:port/app$1/control/$1
```

I'm not entirely sure what to do about the `ProxyPassReverse`, since there is no `ProxyPassReverseMatch`. You might have to get lazy with your `ProxyPassReverse`:

```
ProxyPassReverse /app ajp://tomcathost:port/app
```

I have no idea if the above will work. What I do know is that `mod_proxy` does not rewrite any of the *page content*, so if you find that your URLs aren't formatted properly in the page, `mod_proxy` can't help you. Instead, you'll needto check out `mod_proxy_html` which is not a part of Apache httpd (until httpd 2.4).